# javascript nodejs rounding errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, currency, bitcoin, rounding-error

i want everything to be precise and add up exactly and i can't allow the total to be a penny off.

```
var buy_amount = 132.32000000;                      //amount in bitcoin
var buy_amount_satoshi = buy_amount*100000000;      //amount in satoshi
var sell_rate = 10.00000000;                        //USD rate
var spend_usd = buy_amount_satoshi*sell_rate;   //total USD
var spend_display = spend_usd/100000000;        //total USD user display

console.log(spend_usd.toFixed(8));              //132320000000.00000000
console.log(spend_display.toFixed(8));              //1323.20000000
```

jsfiddle.net/XjLLS/

1. multiply the amount with 100000000 to get the no. of satoshis -
   [Proper Money Handling](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Proper%5fMoney%5fHandling%5f%28JSON-RPC%29)
2. multiply the amount with the rate
3. add 8 decimal places to the result

am i doing it right? i appreciate your help!

---

**UPDATE:**
i'm now use the bigdecimal.js library and made the following snippet:

```
var bigdecimal = require("bigdecimal");

var mode = bigdecimal.RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN(); //default: DOWN
var satoshi = new bigdecimal.BigDecimal("100000000");

var buy_amount = new bigdecimal.BigDecimal("132.32000000"); //amount in bicoin
var amount_minor = buy_amount.multiply(satoshi); //amount in satoshi
var sell_rate = new bigdecimal.BigDecimal("10.00000000"); //sell rate usd
var spend_minor = amount_minor.multiply(sell_rate);
var user_spend = spend_minor.divide(satoshi, 8, mode); //total usd user must spend
var user_display = user_spend.toString();
console.log(user_display);
```

jsfiddle.net/wwpWA/

the default rounding mode is DOWN but i set it to HALF_EVEN aka banker's rounding (banker’s rounding is common when working with money)

i hope all rounding errors are now gone! please correct me if i am wrong!

Comment: You probably want something other than JavaScript then.

Comment: Typically, calculations are done in the minor unit (I guess cents here?) and converted to the major unit (dollars?) at the end. You don't say what level of precision you required.

Comment: the amount is bitcoin and i multiply it with 100000000 to get the minor unit! (1btc = 100000000 satoshi), i need 8 decimal places

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var buy_amount = 132.32000000;                     
var buy_amount_satoshi = (parseFloat(buy_amount)*100000000).toFixed(8);     
var sell_rate = 10.00000000;                        
var spend_satoshi = (parseFloat(buy_amount_satoshi)*parseFloat(sell_rate)).toFixed(8);   
var spend_display = (parseFloat(spend_satoshi)/100000000).toFixed(8);
```

Comment: [*toFixed*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.7.4.5) is a method, perhaps you meant to call it… ;-)

Comment: by using toFixed you will get  8 decimal places. and it is a predefined function

Comment: `parseFloat` applied on a number? Noooooo!

Comment: without adding parseFloat u cant achieve toFixed

Comment: Everything is [`Number`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) - there's no need to parse variables that are already defined with numerical values.  Conversely `toFixed` is only beneficial for display purposes - if you're applying it to variables before you've finished any calculations then you're actively introducing errors in accuracy.

Comment: @Emissary do you think my calculations are accurate, or do i get problems with rounding errors?

Comment: @user3510638 not enough info - I was generalising about the use of `toFixed` in this example which is reducing the precision before the math is finished.

Comment: @Emissary i made a fiddle with my code from above for testing, what infos you need else?

Comment: can i expect that everything is calculated correctly? need some response!